# Got Difficulty in reading Specification?

Tags: arduino

Guys I am making a home automation system very simple one with infrared remote ccontrol of tv remote Now the problem is I wanna buy a some relays to switch 230V AC using my arduino board but can't understand which one to buy I don't want to buy relay module but I wanna buy relay.

Comment: Basically you could follow different strategies: it depends on the purpose of your system. Should it become a commercial product or is it for personal use only. Which power you want to switch e.g. a lamp or an oven.
If you could define your specifications more clearly we can help you for sure.

Comment: its just a domestic experimental nerds project

Answer (score 1):

For you, the safest option is probly be the [Power Switch Tail](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/Pages/default.aspx) It needs no transistors and is very simple, simply set the arduino pin high or low to turn on or off the connected device. Just be careful connecting it to Vacuums and other inductive loads (ie those with motors) as they draw a large current on startup.